# Daemonizing a python script with python-daemon - socket trouble

Tags: python, daemon

I'm try to daemonize some code, but I'm having some trouble.

If I call the code with tklogger(), it runs just fine. However, if I call it in the daemon context, I get the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tklogger.py", line 103, in <module>
    tklogger()
  File "./tklogger.py", line 41, in tklogger
    conn, addr = s.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 195, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
close failed in file object destructor:
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# tklogger, a TK10X GPS tracking device logger

import socket
import time
import daemon

HOST = ''                       # Bind to all interfaces
PORT = 9000                     # Arbitrary non-privileged port
IMEI = '359710040656622'        # Device IMEI
REQUEST_DATA = 1                # Do we want to request data?
INTERVAL = 30                   # How often do we want updates?
LOGDIR = '/var/log/tklogger/'   # Where shall we log?

# END CONFIG

# Establish socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) # allow re-use of the address
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

# Open log files
logger = open(LOGDIR + 'tklogger.log', 'a')
deviceLog = open(LOGDIR + IMEI + '.csv', 'a')

def sendTracker(DATA):
    conn.send(DATA)
    log("\t<< " + DATA)

def log(DATA):
    #print (DATA)
    logger.write(DATA + '\n')
    logger.flush()

def tklogger():
    # Accept connections as they come
    while 1:
        global conn
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        strNow = time.strftime("(%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S)", time.localtime(time.time()))
        log(strNow + ' Accepted connection from ' + addr[0])

        # Fetch data from the socket
        while 1:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data: break
            data = data.rstrip()
            log("\t>> " + data)

            # Check for logon & send data request
            if data == '##,imei:' + IMEI + ',A;':
                sendTracker('LOAD')
                if REQUEST_DATA:
                    time.sleep(5)
                    request = '**,imei:' + IMEI + ',C,' + str(INTERVAL) + 's'
                    sendTracker(request)

            # Check for heartbeat
            if data == IMEI + ';':
                sendTracker('ON')

            # Parse actual data
            if data[:20] == 'imei:' + IMEI:

                # Split into fields
                # id, mode, dateTime, ??, LBS??, ??, fixType??, lat, N/S, lon, E/W, speed?, bearing?
                fields = data.split(',');
                if fields[6] == 'A':

                    # Hopefully we have the protocol right...
                    try:
                        # Convert to degress decimal.
                        latDeg = round(float(fields[7][:2]) + (float(fields[7][2:]) / 60.0), 5)
                        lonDeg = round(float(fields[9][:3]) + (float(fields[9][3:]) / 60.0), 5)
                        if fields[8] == 'S': latDeg = -latDeg
                        if fields[10] == 'W': lonDeg = -lonDeg

                        # Date & time
                        msgDate = fields[2][4:6] + '/' + fields[2][2:4] + '/' + fields[2][:2]
                        msgTime = fields[2][6:8] + ':' + fields[2][8:]

                        # Speed
                        speed = round(1.852 * float(fields[11]), 2)

                        # Bearing 
                        bearing = float(fields[12].rstrip(';'))

                        # Log the device data
                        deviceLog.write(msgDate + ',' + msgTime + ',' + str(latDeg) + ',' + str(lonDeg) + ',' + str(speed) + ',' + str(bearing) + '\n')
                        deviceLog.flush()

                    # Just in case something goes wrong though
                    except: pass

        conn.close()
        strNow = time.strftime("(%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S)", time.localtime(time.time()))
        log(strNow + ' Connection from ' + addr[0] + ' closed')


with daemon.DaemonContext(stderr = logger):
    tklogger()
```

Suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: the simplest fix is to avoid opening files, sockets before the daemonization.

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The act of daemonizing kills all existing sockets. Therefore, you must open your socket `s` after daemonization (inside the DaemonContext).